# Iterm2 weird/duplicate/missing characters when pasting large amounts of code

Tags: iterm2

Does anyone else notice this problem? I get repeated characters or missing characters or weird spacing when pasting into iterm2. Does anyone else notice this?

Like this is what happens when I try pasting a large amount of sql into a psql session on iterm2:

```
syntax error at or near "ORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORabs"
LINE 23: ORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORORabs.ordeOROR DESC
```

Anyone else notice this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTerm2 splits large text into chunks and then sends these chunks with some small delay.
This happens because because iTerm2 has very small delay by default.

To fix large text pasting you can change chunk size and delay options using `defaults` command. Just run commands bellow in your iTerm2:

```
defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 QuickPasteBytesPerCall -int 1024
defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 QuickPasteDelayBetweenCalls -float 0.08
```